# nginx hide rewrite to users

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a domain with two sudomains

```
www.test.com
wiki.test.com
```

As the wiki multilanguage, I have several subdirectories

```
http://wiki.test.com/en for English
http://wiki.test.com/es for Spanish
```

etc.

Until now the root directory at *wiki.test.com* was a simple page asking which language you want and redirecting to a language subdirectory.

But now, I'd like the "choose language page" at

```
http://wiki.test.com
```

to load:

```
http://www.test.com/index.php?page=wiki
```

(and only "wiki.test.com" or "wiki.test.com/", not a subdirectory like "wiki.test.com/ru")

So I thought about

```
server {
    server_name wiki.test.com;
    ...
    index index.php;

    location = / {
       rewrite ^ http://www.test.com/index.php?page=wiki;
#OR    return 302 http://www.test.com/index.php?page=wiki;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

[...]

}
```

But the problem is that when I open *wiki.test.com*, people can see the rewrited url *www.test.com/index.php?page=wiki* while I'd like they only see *wiki.test.com*.

I'm pretty sure the solution is ridiculously simple, and I have made a quite extensive search, but I must not use the good keyword for finding the solutions (I have found lot of similar questions related to proxy_pass, but I have not the impression that proxy_pass is the solution for my case)

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems it's impossible as is, as we change server{} context inside nginx (by changing the subdomain, not just the URI).

I did not really try, but I think I could have used proxy_pass but not only I'd have to use it with

```
location = / {
proxy_pass = http://www.test.com
```

}

but also subdirectories containing images, css js etc. I found it quite a useless complication.

As I have the content of www. on the same machine as wiki., the simplest I have found is to symlink content of www in wiki, and add a simple rewrite

```
location = / {
    rewrite ^ /index.php?page=wiki;
}
```